# How can an object (as in var of type object) be cast using Reflection? (OFX specific)

Tags: c#, system.reflection, ofx

I am using Reflection to avoid explicit casting in deep copying an OFX video plugin state.

```
object pvalue = parameter.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(parameter, null);
```

then later....

```
 OFXParameter newparameter = parameter on new plugin;
            PropertyInfo pi = newparameter.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
            pi.SetValue(newparameter, pvalue, null);
```

I successfully avoided casting the parameter (of which there can be an evolving pool of types).  Now the problem.  Each OFX parameter has a keyframes property containing OFXKeyframes TValue,TKey.  I can not find a way to access the list of keyframes without explicit casting.

```
object keys = parameter.GetType().GetProperty("Keyframes").GetValue(parameter,null);
MethodInfo enumofkeys = keys.GetType().GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
object o = enumofkeys.Invoke(keys,null);
```

Every response I have read explains generic casting with IEnumerable but I must be missing something.  I am restricted to Net 3.5 and with a restriction to 2.0 preferable.  I have no access to IEnumerable without an explicit cast.  The compiler and intellisense always show IEnumerable as IEnumerable<>.

So with either the object keys or the object o (the enumerator) how can I break them down in Reflection to get access?  I have tried invoking the CopyTo method (gained from Reflection) of the Keyframes object but it throws an object not an instance exception (which is proven wrong by an actual explicit cast of the keyframes enumerable.)  Once I figure out how to enumerate through the keys object or figure out how to turn the o object in to a functioning enumerator I am confident I can get the rest of the property values I need. The deep copy structure will never have to be updated even if new parameter types are introduced.

Comment: In what way is using reflection cleaner than using explicit casting?

Comment: Without explicit casting if the OFX parameters are updated (this is being written for a Sony Vegas extension) the deep copy won't care.  If I have to explicitly cast the parameter types in the next OFX revision or Sony Vegas revision I will have to update my extension.  With reflection not caring about the value types any parameter type can be copied without casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot simpler if you used the relevant interface.  In this case, you can use the `IEnumerable` interface.

```
IEnumerable keys = parameter.GetType().GetProperty("Keyframes")
    .GetValue(parameter, null) as IEnumerable;
```

You have to then deal with the type of the enumerated objects, but the enumerable itself is easier to deal with.

`IEnumerable` is in the `System.Collections` namespace, not `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: You missed the point where (possibly because OFX reference types override) I do not have access to IEnumberable.  Your code does not compile.  IEnumerable does not exist.  It exists as IEnumerable<>.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the Sony.Vegas.dll reference may be what is redefining certain things but I will have to investigate further.

Comment: `public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable` as defined in mscorlib.dll since .net 2.0 ... are you sure you can't access `System.Collections.IEnumerable` ? @user2476277

Comment: Ok... part of my Vegas extension was referencing some pretty complicated OFX image manipulation assemblies.  Removing those references (for now) seemed to make System.Collections function like it is supposed to.  So Corey's answer now works for me.  Thank you.

Comment: You might be able to specify it fully as `global::System.Collections.IEnumerable` to get around any overrides placed by other assemblies.